# app does not pick up blazorclasslib pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

i'm using a [razor class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli) contains my _Host.cshtml view :

```
-WebApp
 -Program.cs
 -Startup.cs
-MyRazorClassLib
 -Pages
  -_Host.cshtml
```

and adding app parts in my webapp as follow :

```
            services.AddRazorPages()
                    .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(p =>
                    {
                        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                        {
                            p.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
                        }
                    });
```

the razorclasslib assembly is added to the app parts but i'm having :

```
 Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.
```

I'am missing/messing something ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems yes and documented in [Discovery in Application Parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.1#discovery-in-application-parts)

> The applicationName setting needs to be set to the root assembly used for discovery. The root assembly used for discovery is normally the entry point assembly.

for example :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
     /* set the name of the assembly containing the _Host.cshtml */
     env.ApplicationName = "myAppName";

}
```